# ngRepeat orderBy update after ngModel is updated

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-orderby

I have a list of text fields with a button below it. I can add text fields to that list dynamically with AngularJS.

The text field by default has an empty value. But I want to order the position of the list item as soon as I update the value of that text field. But when I do that the `orderBy` isn't triggered.

How can I make this happen?

Here's a quick demo: http://jsfiddle.net/fqnKt/214/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that this is what you want:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy:'name'">
                <input type="text" ng-model="item.name" /> {{item.name}}
            </li>
        </ul>
        <input ng-model="newItem" type="text"></input>
        <button ng-click="add(newItem)">Add</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

### [Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/yhvssca0/1/)

Answer (score 3):

I just wanted to specifically note why the example was wrong (because I had the same issue even though I was using the orderBy directive).

**DO NOT USE**

```
track by $index
```

**In your ng-repeat**

Comment: I had this issue. Everything looked like it should work, but I had left a "... track by object_id" in there. Removed it and all list sorting worked as expected. Thanks!